# align divs side by side

Tags: html, css

I want to align divs side by side but the padding doesn't let the divs to align side by side and I'm not allowed to remove padding or change anything. just need to add a property and i don't know what property I should add.

Here's the code:

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}
section {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
}
article {
  background: white;
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
}
aside {
  background: pink;
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
}
header,
article,
section,
.module {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<section>
   <article>
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo
         molestias ex officia eligendi reiciendis fuga magnam? Ullam ut ab
         doloremque accusamus iusto aliquam facilis sapiente!
      </p>
   </article>
   <article>
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo
         molestias ex officia eligendi reiciendis fuga magnam? Ullam ut ab
         doloremque accusamus iusto aliquam facilis sapiente!
      </p>
   </article>
</section>
<aside>
   <div className="module">
      <h3>Module</h3>
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio rem
         ab delectus fugit repellendus perspiciatis dolor consequuntur
         tenetur voluptatem a vitae odit aspernatur? Voluptas quisquam
         corporis nostrum aspernatur aliquid harum saepe ab pariatur veniam
         iste ipsam alias nemo voluptatibus doloribus.
      </p>
   </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: @metatron yes it's an assignment

Comment: Google "css box-sizing"

Comment: Have you tried something? can you use flexbox or multicolumns? box-sizing?

Comment: There is only 1 `div` in your question, what are you trying to align?

Comment: @Sfili_81 i tried box-sizing but it didn't do any changes

Comment: what did you try when you "tried box-sizing"?

Comment: @DBS section and aside

Comment: @Johannes border-box on body

Comment: Then you didn't understand it. It only affects the element/s to which you apply it. Think about which elements need to be affected.

Answer (score 0):

box-sizing CSS will fix this issue.
Add default **box-sizing** property to **border-box**

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```